# Is there a way to use recursion with the indexing crate's branded indices to create a tree?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to build a tree using the [indexing crate](https://crates.io/crates/indexing):

```
use indexing::{Container, Index, scope, container::OnlyIndex};

struct Tree<'id>(Option<(Index<'id>, Index<'id>)>);

fn tree<'a>(c: &mut Container<'a, &mut Vec<Tree<'a>>, OnlyIndex>, depth: usize) -> Index<'a> {
    if depth == 0 {
        c.push(Tree(None))
    } else {
        let left = tree(c, depth - 1);
        let right = tree(c, depth - 1);
        c.push(Tree(Some((left, right))))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![];
    scope(&mut v, |v| {
        let mut v = v.only_index();
        tree(&mut v, 3);
        assert_eq!(v.len(), 1 + 2 + 4 + 8);
    });
}
```

This results in a lifetime error:

```
error: borrowed data cannot be stored outside of its closure
  --> src/main.rs:18:23
   |
16 |     let mut v = vec![];
   |         ----- borrowed data cannot be stored into here...
17 |     scope(&mut v, |v| {
   |                   --- ...because it cannot outlive this closure
18 |         let mut v = v.only_index();
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^ cannot be stored outside of its closure
```

Is there a way to correctly define `tree` to work within the indexed scope?

Comment: I believe the doc answer that: "Indices and ranges branded with 'id can not leave the closure. The container can only be accessed and mutated through the Container wrapper passed as the first argument to the indexing scope." https://docs.rs/indexing/0.3.2/indexing/container/fn.scope.html

Comment: It's also included on the [main documentation page](https://docs.rs/indexing/0.3.2/indexing/#basic-parts): _The container and its indices and ranges are “branded” with a lifetime parameter `'id` which is an identity marker. Branded items can't leave their scope, and they tie the items uniquely to a particular container. This makes it possible to trust them._ [only_index](https://docs.rs/indexing/0.3.2/indexing/container/struct.Container.html#method.only_index) returns `'id` branded `Container` -> can't leave the scope.

Comment: I've edited my example to pull the assert into the scope. Can you tell me how this gets the indices outside the scope?

Comment: `Index` can't go out of scope. But your code actually tries to store the `Index` inside `Tree` and then `Tree` inside `v`. And `v` is out of scope. If you want numeric indexes, you can modify `Tree` to `struct Tree(Option<(usize, usize)>);` and then store numeric index instead of `Index` via `c.push(Tree(Some((left.integer(), right.integer()))));`. Check what the [scope](https://github.com/bluss/indexing/blob/0.3.2/src/container.rs#L614-L636) function actually does and read comments.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments pointed out, this is indeed not possible with the indexing crate. However, this doesn't mean that it's generally impossible to store branded indices. In fact, getting rid of the closure will work all right, as in the following code:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::ops::Index;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct InvariantLifetime<'a>(PhantomData<fn(&'a ()) -> &'a ()>);
pub struct Arena<'b, T>(Vec<T>, InvariantLifetime<'b>);
pub struct Idx<'b>(usize, InvariantLifetime<'b>);

impl<'b, T> Arena<'b, T> {
    pub unsafe fn new(_: &'b mut ()) -> Self {
        Arena(vec![], InvariantLifetime(PhantomData))
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, t: T) -> Idx<'b> {
        let i = self.0.len();
        self.0.push(t);
        Idx(i, self.1)
    }
}

impl<'b, T> Index<Idx<'b>> for Arena<'b, T> {
    type Output = T;

    fn index(&self, i: Idx<'b>) -> &T {
        unsafe { &self.0.get_unchecked(i.0) }
    }
}

macro_rules! mk_arena {
    ($arena:ident) => {
        let mut tag = ();
        let mut $arena = unsafe { Arena::new(&mut tag) };
    };
}

struct Tree<'b>(Option<(Idx<'b>, Idx<'b>)>);
fn tree<'b>(a: &mut Arena<'b, Tree<'b>>, d: usize) -> Idx<'b> {
    if d > 0 {
        a.add(Tree(Some((tree(a, d - 1), tree(a, d - 1)))))
    } else {
        a.add(Tree(None))
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    mk_arena!(arena);
    let _ = tree(&mut arena, 3);
}
```

The [compact_arena](https://github.com/llogiq/compact_arena) crate has the same solution, with better docs.